# iOS - getting image with AFNetworking keeps cache

Tags: ios, httprequest, restkit, afnetworking

In my app I'm using RESTKit, so my AFNetworking version isn't the newest. I'm not sure how to check the version of it.
I want to download a picture from my server, and because the response is a jpg file, I'm using AFNetworking. On the first download of the image, it works well. Then I delete the image on the server and upload a new image with the same name. Then if I delete the image in the app and re-download it. In this scenario I still get the old picture from the first time I downloaded.

This is my code:

```
AFHTTPClient *client = [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myserver.com"]];
[client setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:name password:password];

[client getPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"profile-images/%@.jpg", user.name] parameters:@{} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"SUCCES");
        NSData *imageData = responseObject;
        self.tmpImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"FAIL");
        self.tmpImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"];
    }];
```

It looks to me like the app "remembers" the first request I sent to the server when I downloaded the image. And then when I re-download it, it gives me the old picture. Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: code is Working or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got this to work with using `NSMutableURLRequest`. When creating the request I set the `cachePolicy` to `NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData`. Meaning: `request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData;`

Here is the code for sending the request to the server:

```
AFHTTPClient *client = [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://server.com"]];
[client setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:name password:password];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [client requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"profile-images/%@.jpg", user.name] parameters:nil];

request.timeoutInterval = 10;
request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData;

AFImageRequestOperation *operation;
operation = [AFImageRequestOperation imageRequestOperationWithRequest:request imageProcessingBlock:^UIImage *(UIImage *image) {
        NSLog(@"block");
        return image;
} success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
        NSLog(@"SUCCES");
        self.tmpImage = image;
} failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"FAIL");
        self.tmpImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"];
}];

[operation start];
```

Answer (score 0):

when you upload image on server first of all save image in document directory with same name each time. in the code image save name is `@""Profile1.jpeg"`

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{

    UIImage *img = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    img = [self imageWithImage:img scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(70, 70)];

    [btn_Photo setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    NSData *webData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0.5);

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    self.savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"Profile1.jpeg"]];

    [webData writeToFile:self.savedImagePath atomically:YES];

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

        //[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];

    }];
}
```

Using New ANetworking Upload image as below code [New AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *Manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

[Manager POST:str_Submit parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData)
 {

        NSURL *filePath_Profile_Logo = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.savedImagePath];
        [formData appendPartWithFileURL:filePath_Profile_Logo name:@"userfile" error:nil];

 }
success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
 {
     NSLog(@"Success");


 }
failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
 {
     NSLog(@"Fail")
 }];
```

please check your document directory path image is change before upload it or not.
please

Comment: Can I make my request not to use cache? I want to download the last updated profile picture

Comment: your profile picture is also in cache and use it using Document Directory Path.

Comment: I want my second download to not use the cache. Is it possible?

Comment: Not got at second Time. Because when remove apps from iphone then all is clear.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand your answer.

Comment: you can not get your old image.

Comment: if you want to old image you have to save image with different name in Document directory.

Comment: I don't want the old image. I want the new image. I keep getting the old image. that's my problem.

Comment: Ya you can got both image if save with different name in document directory.

Comment: if same name in document directory then you got only new image. you can not keep old image.

Comment: I'm not saving them. I'm putting the image in an object `self.tmpImage`. but it keeps putting the old image and not the new one.

Comment: sorry,i can't understand, what you want?

Comment: When I send the request I posted in my question, at the first time I get the image from the server. But when I send another request, I get the same image as I got at the first time, even if the image was changed. I want to get the **last** image that is on the server. meaning, I do **not** want the cache to be used.

Comment: At first time you upload image and got it.

Comment: after second time upload new image but you got fitst uploaded image from the server.